High school conceptual integration question
the question:
Given $|\int_a^b f(x) dx| = \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$ and $f ' (x) \ne 0 $ at any $x \in (a,b) $; if $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$, f(x) being continuous and differentiable in (a,b) then $\int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx=0$ implies
$(A) g(x) = 0$ has at most one root in $(a,b) $
$(B) g(x) = 0$ has at least one root in $(a,b) $
$(C) g(x) = 0$ has exactly one root in $(a,b)$
$(D) g(x)=0$
No solution was given in the book ...
answer given in the book was $\textbf{(C)}$
$\textbf{My attempt:}$
From $|\int_a^b f(x) dx| = \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$, concluded that $f(x)>0$,
using integration by parts in $ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx = \left.g(x)\right\rvert_a^b \int_a^b f(x)dx - \int_a^b g'(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx$$\textbf{(1)}$
simplifying $\left.g(x)\right\rvert_a^b = \int_0^b f(t) dt-\int_0^a f(t) dt= \int_0^b f(t) dt+\int_a^0 f(t) dt= \int_a^b f(t) dt$
and $g'(x)=f(x)$
$\textbf{(1)}$, $ \int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx=( \int_a^b f(f)dt)^2 - \int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx=0$$\textbf{(2)}$
Now using integration by parts again in $$\begin{align}\int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx&= \int_a^b f(x)dx  \int_a^b f(x)dx- \int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx\\ &=(\int_a^b f(x)dx)^2-\int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx\end{align}$$
$\textbf{(2)}$, $\int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx=0$
I do not know how to proceed after this.
also I am not sure if integration by parts can be used like I did in $\int_a^b f(x)(\int f(x)dx)dx$.
and the fact $f(x) > 0$ or $f '(x)$ not equals to $0 $;  is not used.
please help...

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Using integration by parts at the very beginning is a mistake. If I have $\int u\cdot u'$ as an integral then what is its direct antiderivative?

@JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the suggestion, I have added the question in MathJax.

Before the solution, you should be familiar with Intermediate Value Theorem.
$\int_{a}^{b} g(x)f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dg(x)=\frac{1}{2}g^2(b)-\frac{1}{2}g^2(a)$, where $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$.
Since $\int_{a}^{b} g(x)f(x)dx=0$, we get $g^{2}(b)=g^2(a).$
From $|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx|=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$, we conclude that $f(x)$ is either non-positive or non-negative on $(a,b).$ WLOG, suppose that $f(x)\geq0$ on $(a,b)$, then $g(x)$ is non-decreasing on $(a,b)$, so that we have either $g(a)=g(b)$ or $g(a)=-g(b).$
For the First case, we conclude that $f(x)=0$, thus we get nothing for $g(x)$.
For the second case, using the theorem I have mentioned above.
